# SQL - trimming values before bracket

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, substring, trim

I have a column of values where some values contain brackets with text which I would like to remove. This is an example of what I have and what I want:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(column_i_have varchar(50), 
column_i_want varchar(50))

INSERT INTO test (column_i_have, column_i_want)
VALUES ('hospital (PWD)', 'hopistal'), 
('nursing (LLC)','nursing'),
('longterm (AT)', 'longterm'),
('inpatient', 'inpatient')
```

I have only come across approaches that use the number of characters or the position to trim the string, but these values have varying lengths. One way I was thinking was something like:

```
TRIM('(*',col1)
```

Doesn't work. Is there a way to do this in postgres SQL without using the position? THANK YOU!

Comment: Why are you storing comma delimited values? That's a huge mistake to begin with.

Comment: Is that string a single value, or each one is on a separate row?

Comment: sorry, this was just an example to illustrate the problem. I will update

Comment: each value is a separate row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the values contain "valid" brackets, then you may use [split_part](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function without any regular expressions:

> ```
> select
>   test.*,
>   trim(split_part(column_i_have, '(', 1)) as res
> from test
> ```
>
> ```
> column_i_have  | column_i_want | res      
> :------------- | :------------ | :--------
> hospital (PWD) | hopistal      | hospital 
> nursing (LLC)  | nursing       | nursing  
> longterm (AT)  | longterm      | longterm 
> inpatient      | inpatient     | inpatient
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0027dfa1c20c94c63f11a7ac39cae6bb)*

Answer (score 1):

You can replace partial patterns using regular expressions. For example:

```
select *, regexp_replace(v, '\([^\)]*\)', '', 'g') as r
from (
  select '''hospital (PWD)'', ''nursing (LLC)'', ''longterm (AT)'', ''inpatient''' as v
) x
```

Result:

```
r
-------------------------------------------------
'hospital ', 'nursing ', 'longterm ', 'inpatient'
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=747f39a0d160f73821e212e8cac8e437).

Answer (score 1):

Could it be as easy as:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_i_have, '\w+') AS column_i_want FROM test
```

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/733172/5/0)

---

If not, and you still want to use `SUBSTRING()` to get upto but exclude paranthesis, then maybe:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_i_have, '^(.+?)(?:\s*\(.*)?$') AS column_i_want FROM test
```

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/733172/6/0)

---

But if you really are looking upto the opening paranthesis, then maybe just use `SPLIT_PART()`:

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART(column_i_have, ' (', 1) AS column_i_want FROM test
```

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/733172/8/0)